# Mismatched question count on tag info page and tagged question page

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonyms

There are 100 questions tagged as [bit-shift-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-shift-operators) as shown on "tagged question" page.
[image]

However, in the [tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bit-shift-operators/synonyms) page, only 99 questions are claimed to be tagged with `bit-shift-operators`.
[image]

Comment: Is it caching? It always is...

Comment: @rene I don't think so. I can reproduce it in the incognito mode of my browser. Also I can reproduce it even after I cleared my browser cache.

Comment: Caching happens both in your browser and on stack exchange servers

Comment: Client side I repro this..so this behavior is induced between my pc and the view/controler that rendered that page.

Comment: @rene the bug is in the cache itself this time, or so it appears. For some reason one question with that tag slipped away when one cache was built... hopefully they rebuild it at some point so let's wait and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works correctly now. Both pages show the same value.